# Sql Server 2008R2 JavaKerberos does not recognize Krb5LoginModule tickets

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, active-directory, kerberos

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        Subject subject=  new Subject();
        Krb5LoginModule krb5=new Krb5LoginModule();
        final String name="login@REALM.COM";
        final char[] password="PASSWORD".toCharArray();
        Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("debug","true");
        map.put("useTicketCache","false");
        map.put("doNotPrompt","false");
        map.put("tryFirstPass","true");
        Map<String,Object> shared=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        shared.put("javax.security.auth.login.name",name);
        shared.put("javax.security.auth.login.password",password);
        krb5.initialize(subject,new CallbackHandler(){},map);
        krb5.login();
        krb5.commit();

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:PORT;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        conn.close();
        krb5.logout();
}
```

That throws the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:00abf877-8518-4d2c-a4e7-6b1b4ce65197
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2691)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at a.a.a.Test.main(main.java:92)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:800)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:671)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:584)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:133)
```

Ive dug around a bit and it seems the sql connection is completely ignoring the krb5, and trying to create itself a new one. The commit returns true and prints "[Krb5LoginModule] authentication succeeded" to the console. Then later the doNotPrompt field magically becomes true and throws the error.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using SPNEGO. It was a much easier alternative.

Do not use Krb5LoginModule. Do not use sqljdbc less than v3. Do not use Kerberos. Do not test with unprivileged account.